# Unable to successfully run Google Drive GDAA demo app

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-play-services, google-drive-android-api

I am having difficulty executing the sample Google Drive app successfully. When I run the app on my Moto X I receive the following error:

```
I/DriveDemo: GoogleApiClient connection failed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED, resolution=PendingIntent{867e070: android.os.BinderProxy@13cdfe9}, message=null}
```

Steps I have taken so far:

1. Created an OAuth certificate.
2. Enabled the Google Drive API.
3. Followed the instructions at https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating to integrate sign-in.
4. Moved client_id.json to the app directory

manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.lightkeeper54.chuck.drivedemo" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
            <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.apps.drive.APP_ID" android:value="id=MY_ID" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.apps.drive.DRIVE_OPEN" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.google-apps.drive-sdk.MY_ID" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MY_ID is the numeric ID from the API Manager Credentials screen, using the numeric prefix up to the hyphen in the Client ID. I am unclear as to whether this is correct, since I have been unable to find much information regarding this.

build.gradle (project)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle (app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.lightkeeper54.chuck.drivedemo"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you using the REST API or GDAA?

Comment: I am using GDAA

Comment: Your step 3 isn't required for a GDAA application. Takre a step back and make sure you understand the difference between a GDAA app and an Android app that uses GDrive. You'll probably find that as you click around online resources and search results, you inadvertantly cross the line from GDAA to REST. A clue is that GDAA works completely offline.